# How to force copy location of a vertex to modified object?

Tags: constraints

I have two objects, out of which:

- one (d1) is making rotation and translation.
- The other object (d2) has curve modifier applied to it.

The requirement is: d2 should copy the location of d1 (actually, an empty that d1 is parented to) during motion, with vertices A and B sticking together all along.

But, since there is a curve modifier on d2, vertex B get shifted to a lower position and the copy constraint uses the unmodified location of B for the location copying resulting in a gap between the two vertices.

Is there a way to force vertex B of the object d2 to stick to vertex A of d1 regardless of the modifiers on either objects?

I also tried parenting an empty (e1) to the vertex and creating another empty (e2) at the modified location for d2 to copy the location of, but that didn't help.

Here are the steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Open the attached blend file
2. Go to the time-line view at the bottom and move the pointer to zero frame position. The objects (page_0...page_5) on the right hand side are all straight (i.e. unbent) and stacked on top of each other. Each page is parented to a rotation axis and has a curve modifier applied to it.
3. As you move the pointer to frame 13 the top object (page_0) rotates to the left side, the shape-key on the curve makes the page to bend, page_1 parent empty copies the location of the page_0 empty during this motion, so two top objects are stuck together
4. Now if you continue moving the pointer to frame # 25, page_1 undergoes rotation as well as translation, it shifts to left side, page_0 also rotates by a few positive degrees so that the two pages are aligned in their angle. Page_2 parent empty copies the location of page_1 empty during this time so these two pages are together.
5. The requirement is just as the right hand side page is stuck to the turning page, the left hand one should also have the same location so there is no gap between the pages during the rotation. But as you can see in the animation, this is not happening because of the curve modified bending the vertex that's supposed to be copying the location of the turning object.

[image: Copy Location Issue]

[image]

Comment: Hi, since this could be particularly bound to how you specifically set up your contraints, modifiers, I suggest you to share the file (use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to upload the file, then paste the provided link in your question's text), to make finding a solution easier.

Comment: Sure. Here's the link:[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4073" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4073/). Please have a look at the first 3 left hand side objects at the time of rotation.

Comment: ok, I pasted your link in the question text, but in the file objects seem to be named differently, not d1/d2, e1/e2... please edit your question and add some reproduction step...

Comment: Appreciate your help. I've added the reproduction steps.